# Regex for git commit (SHA1) inside or not a markdown link

Tags: javascript, regex, git, sha1

I want to parse a line having the word `Commits` (case insensitive) followed by a colon, a possible space and either two commits hash separated by three dots or the same included in a markdown link.

For example, for the following lines:

```
commits:56af25a...d3fead4
Commits: [56af25a...d3fead4](https://github.com/Glimpse/Semantic-Release-Notes/compare/56af25a...d3fead4)
```

I want to get:

```
56af25a...d3fead4
[56af25a...d3fead4](https://github.com/Glimpse/Semantic-Release-Notes/compare/56af25a...d3fead4)
```

So I tested the basic expression [`/^commits:[ ]{0,}(.*)/i`](https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/1), it works but I get anything behind `commits:`, not just two commits.

I also tested [`/^commits:[ ]*([\[.*?\]\(]?\b[0-9a-f]{5,40}\b\.\.\.\b[0-9a-f]{5,40}\b[\)]?)/i`](https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/7) but I only get the two commits, e.g.:

```
56af25a...d3fead4
[56af25a...d3fead4
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want with one regex, or is it better to have two different regex?

I only want the value after `commits:` if :

- It's two commit hashes separated by three dots: `56af25a...d3fead4`
- The same thing, but as a markdown link text: `[56af25a...d3fead4](anything in here)`

It have to fail if there is anything before or after.
So typically the following string are bad:

```
Commits: [56af25a...d3fead4](https://github.com/Glimpse/Semantic-Release-Notes/compare/56af25a...d3fead4) Commits:
Commits: test[56af25a...d3fead4](https://github.com/Glimpse/Semantic-Release-Notes/compare/56af25a...d3fead4)
Commits: test [56af25a...d3fead4](https://github.com/Glimpse/Semantic-Release-Notes/compare/56af25a...d3fead4)
```

Comment: post the example which produces the problem. You mean this https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^commits:[ ]{0,}(?:([a-z0-9A-Z]+\.{3}[a-z0-9A-Z]+)|(\[[a-z0-9A-Z]+\.{3}[a-z0-9A-Z]+\]\(https?:\/\/\S+\)))$
```

Simply try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/9

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't clear in my question: I want to be sure that there is two commit hashes after the `commits:` part, included or not in a markdown link.

Comment: It is bad because each line is processed as a particular syntax, so I need a line to be recognize as "commits" only if it succeed the conditions stated in my question.
Nevertheless thanks for your suggestion, I haven't think about non-capturing group and alternatives!